# Force custom property to expand in IDE

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I created a custom component. Is there a way to have some of its properties always expanded in  the property editor? They contain colors which are better to view this way.

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4086979/897326) - does it solve your problem?

Comment: well... this won't apply to my problem because I don't use a derivate component nor a visible (on form) property. I just create my own component and have few properties which needs to be expanded at DESIGN-TIME and in PROPERTY EDITOR (not on form).