# How to create an array of the same properties?

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

So pretty much, what I'm trying to do is create a properties grid. It will hold things like input 0-5 or like output 1-64, which will have sub-properties like name, id, etc. Right now my code is very straight forward, and I initialize each one individually. That caused a problem when I wanted to save them to a text file and realized that doing it that way will cause walls of code. Instead of just being able to do a for loop, I would have to grab each one individually to write to the text file. I was wondering if there was a better approach to doing this with an array or list.

Here is what I have right now:

```
        [CategoryAttribute("Input 0"), DescriptionAttribute("Name of Input 0"), DisplayName("Input 0: Name")]
    public string IName_0
    {
        get {return _Iname[0];}
        set {_Iname[0] = value;}
    }

    [CategoryAttribute("Input 0"), DescriptionAttribute("ID of Input 0"), DisplayName("Input 0: ID")]
    public int IID_0
    {
        get { return _IID[0]; }
        set { if ((64 > value) && (value >= 0)) _IID[0] = value; }
    }
    [CategoryAttribute("Input 1"), DescriptionAttribute("Name of Input 1"), DisplayName("Input 1: Name")]
    public string IName_1
    {
        get { return _Iname[1]; }
        set { _Iname[1] = value; }
    }

    [CategoryAttribute("Input 1"), DescriptionAttribute("ID of Input 1"), DisplayName("Input 1: ID")]
    public int IID_1
    {
        get { return _IID[1]; }
        set { if ((64 > value) && (value >= 0)) _IID[1] = value; }
```

It goes on like that for each input. I have been looking everywhere, and I can't find a good fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to realize that containing your properties in a collection will cause them to be grouped together under it, when displayed on your PropertyGrid.
Therefore, having a collection of `string`s and another of `int`s will break your current structure, of:

1. Having pairs of properties (name and ID) grouped together;
2. Having all the properties on the root level of the property grid.

Having said that, you could solve issue #1 by making #2 a bit worse.
create two classes:

- `MyClass` - containing a `Name` and `IID` properties.
- `MyClassCollection` - a container class (most likely using an underlying List).

To mitigate issue #2, you can add code to expand all nodes at initialization [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086105/expand-c-sharp-propertygrid-on-show).

If you try this, you will notice that the "containers" (`MyClassCollection` and `MyClass`) will have some undesired decription text appearing next to them when displayed.
This is where [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4448/Customized-display-of-collection-data-in-a-Propert) comes in handy.

Your property would then be:

```
[DisplayName("Some info here"),
DescriptionAttribute("Some more descriptive info here...")]
virtual public MyClassCollection MyData { get; set; }
```

and your class definitions would be along the lines of:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name;  }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public int IID
    {
        get { return _iid; }
        set { if ((64 > value) && (value >= 0)) _iid = value; }
    }

    private string _name;
    private int    _iid;
}

public class MyClassCollection : CollectionBase
{
    // See the article for code for the overrides (for CollectionBase) and implementation (for ICustomTypeDescriptor)
}
```

If you look at the article mentioned above, regarding the tweaking of the display text of the container classes, you'll have to make some adjustments to the classes above.